# phantomjs - disable responsive nature (tried setting viewportsize to bigger value)

Tags: javascript, python, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to generate screenshot of my website. It is responsive. When reduced size, the contents split and webpage appears like a narrow one. I cant disable this from css for now as resposive css is mixed badly with other js. So, I tried setting page.viewportSize = {'width': 1024, height: 768 }, but still it is generating screenshot as if website viewed from a device of small width.

```
 var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://127.0.0.1', function () {
page.viewportsize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };
console.log(JSON.stringify(page.viewportsize));
page.render('local.png');
```

Reason for including tags: python is, they might have used this library.

Comment: It would be good to see the page you are looking at.  To start: set viewportsize before opening the page.  Then, you say that your responsive layout relies on JavaScript.  PhantomJS may not support some of the methods you are using.  What happens when you change the viewportsize before opening the page?

Comment: Have you tried setting `page.viewportsize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };` before you open the page?

Comment: @ChrisP Since you answered first as comment, please write it again as 'new answer', so I can mark it as correct. Feeling very bad that I missed simple thing.

Comment: Posted as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to see the page you are looking at. To start: set `viewportsize` before opening the page. What happens when you change the viewportsize before opening the page?